# A mount of box.com as davfs2 hangs and does not become unstuck

Tags: ubuntu, webdav, kubuntu, davfs2

I have mounted box.com on a Ubuntu 11.04 system, and it worked fine.  For a day.  It is mounted with the davfs2 file system.  But after a day it froze, and all shells that try to list or do anything in the parent directory of the mount point freezes.

I have read on serverfault that a reboot might be the only way to resolve the dreaded "D" IO probmem (reuqest_wait_answer).  Which is fine if it happened only once.  But more interesting is what caused it to hang and how I can prevent this in the future.  This is how I mounted the point

```
https://dav.box.com/dav /home/myuser/box.com davfs rw,user,noauto 0 0
```

I bring that up because I don't have the overview of all options to the module, maybe something will help?

To sum my question up:

1. How do I unstuck the stuck davfs2 share when all operations (including mount -o remount and umount) just freeze?
2. How do I prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
fusermount -u /home/myuser/box.com
```

(Try that with an ordinary user account and if that does not work, then as root)

Comment: +1: While `umount -l` froze, `fusermount -uz` did the lazy umount just fine for me.